# Storing in PostgreSQL using Python Polars

Tags: postgresql, python-polars

I want to store a datframe from a parquet file into a PostgreSQL using Polars using this code:

```
def store_in_postgresql(df):
    password = 'anon'
    username = 'postgres'
    database = 'nyc_taxis'
    uri = f'postgresql://{username}:{password}@localhost:5432/{database}'
    engine = create_engine(uri)
    common_sql_state = "SQLSTATE: 42P07"
    
    try:
        df.write_database(table_name, connection=uri,
                          engine='adbc', if_exists='replace')
        print('loading has been completed!')
    except Exception as e:
        if(common_sql_state in str(e)):
            df.write_database(table_name, connection=uri,
                          engine='adbc', if_exists='append')
            print('loading has been completed!')
        else:
            print(e)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: [libpq] Failed to execute COPY statement: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR ERROR:  COPY file signature not recognized
. SQLSTATE: 22P04
```

the code store dataframes with small sizes like 4 million rows (200 mb) but when I want to store a big dataframe with 18 million rows (500 mb) I get the error above, is there a way to fix the code or perhaps slice the dataframe to have it stored in the database? thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Add to your question how you are creating the dataframe. 2) Look at the Postgres log to see if it provides more information. My suspicion is you are stitching together NYC taxi data files to get a a bigger file and it is producing something `COPY` does not understand.

Comment: If you can create a reproducible test case, this may be something that could be reported as a "bug". (Although it's unclear if the issue is in the underlying `adbc` library.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, it was a memory problem.
since the function works for smaller dataframes and not big ones I made a new function to split the big dataframe into smaller chunks and then they are processed by the function above:

```
def store_by_chunking(df, num_of_chunks):
try:
    length = len(df) // num_of_chunks
    j = 0
    list_of_chunks = []
    
    for i in range(num_of_chunks):
        list_of_chunks.append(j)
        j += length
    list_of_chunks.append(len(df))
    
    print(list_of_chunks)
    
    for i in range(num_of_chunks):
        sliced_df = df.slice(list_of_chunks[i], list_of_chunks[i+1])
        store_in_postgresql(sliced_df)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

this code has not given me an error so far, hope it helps people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to achieve this (at least for me):

```
    batch_size = 10000
    for i in range(0, df.height, batch_size):
        sub_df = df[i:i+batch_size]
        sub_df.write_database(table_name=table_name,
            connection=connection_string,
            engine='adbc',
            if_exists='replace')
```